# Sending File Over Python Socket - Hanging at socket.sendall

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, sockets

I've written what I thought was a fairly simple script to download files over the network with Python sockets, but the server hangs on socket.sendall on the server side. I can get the file I want once, but subsequent calls to senddata cause a crash.

After looking into this a bit more, I'm fairly sure it's something to do with how I'm packing the header data, meaning it may well be a low-level issue which is beyond my ken.

For context: the 'master' code is running on an x86 computer, while the 'slave' code is running on a Raspberry Pi Zero (ARM).

The header's defined in the code, but here's an overview:

- File length and length of filename are bundled into an 8-byte header of two uints.
- Filename and the first chunk of (h264 video) data are bundled together into a 1kb initial send.
- The server then sends further data in 1kb chunks until it's sent the whole file.

I'm pretty puzzled about why this doesn't work as it seems like a routine bit of code.

### Slave (Server)

```
#takes filename and sends the data to the connected socket
def senddata(filename,socket):
    try:
        filehandle = open(filename,'rb')
    except IOError:
        socket.sendall('ABORT')
        print 'File ' +filename+ ' not found; not sending...'
    else:
        #writes 8 byte header consisting of:
        #length of file (including filename) in kb (4b)
        #length of filename (4b)
        numbytes = struct.pack("<I",math.ceil((os.stat(filename).st_size + len(filename)) / 1024))
        #amount of KB (1024) to receive, written to 4-byte integer
        filenamebytes = struct.pack("<I",len(filename))
        print 'Sending '+filename+'...'
        socket.sendall(numbytes + filenamebytes)
        data = filename + filehandle.read(1024 - len(filename))
        while True:
            socket.sendall(data)
            data = filehandle.read(1024)
            if not data:
                break
        filehandle.close()
        print 'Send complete.'
```

### Master (Client)

```
def ReceiveDownload(socket):
    #gets header
    data = socket.recv(8)
    if data != 'ABORT':
        filekb = struct.unpack("<I",data[:4])[0]#endianness may be affecting data transfer
        filenamebytes = struct.unpack("<I",data[4:])[0]
        data = socket.recv(1024)
        filename = data[:filenamebytes]
        curkb = 1
        print 'Getting '+filename+"..."
        writeto = open('./footage/'+filename,'wb')
        while curkb <= filekb:
            print '\r' + str(curkb) + "/" + str(filekb),
            sys.stdout.flush()
            writeto.write(data)
            data = socket.recv(1024)
            curkb += 1
        writeto.close()
        print 'Download of '+filename+' successful.'
    else:
        print 'Download failed.'
```

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.13

Comment: I suspect that you're simply not reading all of the data at the client end - keep in mind that `.recv(1024)` can return less data than that, if there isn't that much data in the network buffers at the moment.  Your strange "round off to a multiple of 1K" scheme isn't helping - why are you not sending the actual length of the file, so you'd KNOW exactly when the end is reached?

Comment: Good point; the motivation for using 1kb rounding was that video files tend to be pretty big and I was worried about going past the limit of a uint if I used bytes as my unit. This is probably premature optimisation though.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself with the advice from jasonharper.

By switching out the code measuring in kb with more normal code which worked in bytes, all data from the socket was always read. I'm not sure whether the original cause of this fault was down to a floating point issue or some other reason, but it worked. If I need more capacity I'll switch to using Longs.

For the sake of code readability and to decrease the chance of rounding errors, I also stopped the filename and data being lumped together into a single transmission block.

The original code was overengineered when much simpler code would have done the trick.

Revised code:

### Client

```
def ReceiveDownload(socket):
    #gets header
    data = socket.recv(8)
    if data != 'ABORT':
        fileb = struct.unpack("<I",data[:4])[0]#endianness may be affecting data transfer
        filenamebytes = struct.unpack("<I",data[4:])[0]
        data = socket.recv(filenamebytes)
        filename = data
        curb = 0
        print 'Getting '+filename+"..."
        writeto = open('./footage/'+filename,'wb')
        while curb < fileb:
            sys.stdout.flush()
            data = socket.recv(1024)
            writeto.write(data)
            curb += len(data)
            print '\r' + str(curb) + "/" + str(fileb),
        writeto.close()
        print 'Download of '+filename+' successful.'
    else:
        print 'Download failed.'
```

### Server

```
def senddata(filename,socket):
    try:
        filehandle = open(filename,'rb')
    except IOError:
        socket.sendall('ABORT')
        print 'File ' +filename+ ' not found; not sending...'
    else:
        #writes 8 byte header consisting of:
        #length of file in kb (4b)
        #length of filename (4b)
        numbytes = struct.pack("<I",math.ceil(os.stat(filename).st_size))
        #amount of KB (1024) to receive, written to 4-byte integer
        filenamebytes = struct.pack("<I",len(filename))
        print 'Sending '+filename+'...'
        socket.sendall(numbytes + filenamebytes)
        data = filename
        socket.sendall(data)
        while True:
            data = filehandle.read(1024)
            socket.sendall(data)
            if not data:
                break
        filehandle.close()
        print 'Send complete.'
```